# Using i18next with TypeScript: How to Support Prefixed Namespace Keys in the t Function

Tags: typescript, next.js, i18next, react-i18next, next-i18next

I am using [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/overview/typescript) with typescript and generating resource types from JSON with translation resources with [i18next-resources-for-ts](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-resources-for-ts). Everything works well, but I'm facing an issue when using prefixed namespaces with the `t` function from the `useTranslation()` hook. I am not looking for `useTranslation('common')` or `t('auth.login.text', { ns: 'common' })`, which works fine and is typed correctly.

Here's a simplified version of my `i18next.d.ts`:

```
import 'i18next';
import common from '../public/locales/en/common.json';

const resources = {
  common,
} as const;

declare module 'i18next' {
  interface CustomTypeOptions {
    returnNull: false;
    defaultNS: 'common';
    resources: typeof resources;
  }
}
```

and set up of `i18next.ts`

```
import commonDe from '../public/locales/de/common.json';
import commonEn from '../public/locales/de/common.json';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const resources = {
  de: {
    common: commonDe,
  },
  en: {
    common: commonEn,
  },
};

export const defaultNS = 'common';

i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    resources,
    ns: [defaultNS],
    defaultNS,
    lng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    returnNull: false,
  });

export default i18next;
```

The problem arises when attempting to use a prefixed namespace in the `t` function:

```
const { t } = useTranslations();
t('common:auth.login.text')
```

Then types doesn't work.

I know that I could specify `ns` as options for `t` function or select it already in `useTranslation` hook. But I would also like to support the prefixed way as above in the translation key.

Any suggestions or ideas on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@hokwanhung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14499516/hokwanhung) points I got to a working solution.

As he perfectly described, my issue was in `react-i18next`. But in my case, I need to use `useTranslations()` with an array argument, simple string doesn't work.

```
const { t } = useTranslation('common'); // doesn't enable keys with namespace prefixes in my case
```

**Working solution with settings in question:**

```
const { t } = useTranslation(['common']); // use array here
t('common:auth.login.text'); // works fine now
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not really about `i18next-resource-for-ts`, but with the way of how `react-i18next` works.

In `i18next`, this would work well:

```js
// when you call i18next directly,
i18next.t('common:auth.login.text'); // work fine, not recommended, but what you want specifically.
i18next.t('auth.login.text', { ns: 'common' }); // work fine too.
```

However, with `react-i18next`, you must specify the `namespace(s)` for multiple translation files with the three methods of `useTranslation()`, `withTranslation()` and `Translation` (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://react.i18next.com/guides/multiple-translation-files)):

```js
// when you call react-i18next methods,
const { t } = useTranslations();
t('common:auth.login.text'); // fail.
```

When the three methods are passed with no parameters, it recognised the default `namespace` specified in the `i18next.ts` document. However, whenever you want to specify `namespace(s)` in the `t` function, it is best to perform like below:

```
const { t } = useTranslation('common'); // and when you have multiple, put all of them in an array.
t('common:auth.login.text'); // would work fine.
```

Hope the above answer helps.